# Jsoup Parsing adding delimiter

Tags: html, jsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML file using Jsoup and removing the html tags. Whenever I remove an HTML tag I want a delimiter(fullstop) instead of the tag.

for example if the html is:

`<head>
    <title>N-gram and Fast Pattern Extraction Algorithm - CodeProject</title>`

I want the output to be

`..N-gram and Fast Pattern Extraction Algorithm - CodeProject.`

I am a newcomer to Jsoup. Is it possible using Jsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with the recursion. For a big DOM it might cause you problems, memory-wise or performance-wise.

```
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String html = "<html><head>" +
                                    "<title>Introduction</title>" +
                                "</head>" +
                                    "<body>" +
                                    "<a target=\"_top\" href=\"/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp\">HTML Events</a>"+
                                    "<a target=\"_top\" href=\"/tags/ref_canvas.asp\">HTML Canvas</a>"+
                                    "<a target=\"_top\" href=\"/tags/ref_av_dom.asp\">HTML Audio/Video</a>"+ 
                                    "<a target=\"_top\" href=\"/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp\">HTML Doctypes</a></body></html>";

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
            System.out.println(doc);

            System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------------\n");
            replaceTag(doc.children());

            System.out.println(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void replaceTag(Elements els) {
        ListIterator<Element> iter = els.listIterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Element el = iter.next();  
            replaceTag(el.children());
            if(el.parentNode() != null)
                el.replaceWith(new TextNode("." + el.text().trim() + ".", ""));
        }
    }
}
```