# Jsoup Replace Tags with Delimiter without Recursion

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML file and I want to get text from it. I decided to use Jsoup but I have one problem. I want to iterate text of a tag one by one.

Here is a similar question: [Jsoup Parsing adding delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718983/jsoup-parsing-adding-delimiter) with a "recursive" answer. I don't want to implement a recursive solution because of memory issues.

My question is does Jsoup has a built in function to give me clean text with a pre defined delimiter instead of tags or is there any method I can iterate element by element (an element does not have child element) without a recursive solution?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to use a streaming parser like [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/) instead, which implements SAX2 API. Since it does not build the DOM tree, it takes the same amount of memory regardless of source document size. If you haven't dealt with SAX before, here is a little [tutorial](http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html).

To simply clean the text (inserting dots instead of both opening and closing tags) you may use the following snippet:

```
package com.example;

import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    final static String SEPARATOR = ".";
    StringBuilder builder;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        builder.append(SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        builder.append(SEPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    public String cleanHtml(InputStream inputStream) {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.setContentHandler(this);
        try {
            parser.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your example uses tagsoup?

Comment: @kamaci Yes, I've added `import`s to the listing to make it more clear.